# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame5.!frame.!label"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a gesture based project with GUI made in Tkinter. Now we are transmitting the camera capture to the window by converting frames into PIL image and putting it into a Label. The main structure for this part is as follows: root->"main_win"(Frame)->"frame_f1"(Frame)->"Label_l2"(Label)->cam input.

The code for cam input is:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    desture_l2.imgtk = imgtk
    desture_l2.configure(image=imgtk)
    desture_l2.update()
    if(keyboard.is_pressed('q')):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now the error that is occurring is that whenever we switch to a different frame(say "Home" or "Setting") we get the following message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "homen.py", line 215, in desture
    desture_l2.configure(image=imgtk)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame5.!frame.!label"
```

Can someone shed light unto this issue pls??

Comment: Obviously the widget `desture_l2` is destroyed when you switch frame.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Since you don't provide a [mre], we cannot help.

Comment: I have added minimal reproducible example in the answer section, please give it a look

Comment: @acw1668 can you please take a look!

Comment: You have destroyed all widgets in `main_win` (including `desture_l2`) inside `hide_all_frames()`.  Don't destroy widgets and just hide `main_win`.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal Reproducible Example for the above error:

```
edit_win = Frame(root)

main_win = Frame(root)

def mainfunc():

    hide_all_frames()
    main_win.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    desture_f1 = Frame(main_win,width=200, height=200)
    desture_f1.pack()
    #Capture video frames
    desture_l2 = Label(desture_f1)
    desture_l2.pack()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        desture_l2.imgtk = imgtk
        desture_l2.configure(image=imgtk)
        desture_l2.update()
        if(keyboard.is_pressed('q')):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def edit():

    hide_all_frames()
    edit_win.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    edit_l1 = Label(edit_win, text="You are on Settings page", foreground="green3")
    edit_l1.pack(pady=20)

def hide_all_frames():

    if main_win.winfo_exists:
        for widget in main_win.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        main_win.pack_forget()
    if edit_win.winfo_exists:
        for widget in edit_win.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        edit_win.pack_forget()

def nav():

    mainmenu = Menu(root)
    mainmenu.add_command(label="Edit", command=edit)
    root.config(menu=mainmenu)

nav()

mainfunc()
```